# Jquery in IE can't get the whole HTML tag and contents

Tags: jquery

I have content with `<ticker>` tags that I want to inject ticker symbols in. The ticker tags in HTML look like:

```
<ticker symbol="AAPL">Apple</ticker>
```

The expected result is...

```
Apple (AAPL)
```

So I have jquery code like so...

```
jQuery.each($("ticker"), function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text()+" ("+$(this).attr("symbol")+")");
 });
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE I get this:

```
 (AAPL)Apple</ticker>
```

So when IE grabs a `$("ticker")` element it's only taking the `<ticker symbol="AAPL">` tag, not the whole element, and replacing it with the string. Does anyone know what will work for all browsers?

Comment: You're making up your own tags, so you're on thin ice.  You'd probably be better off with `<span class='ticker' data-symbol='AAPL'>Apple</span>` which IE would completely understand (as would every other browser). (Thus, the title of the question is actually wrong: that's not an HTML tag.)

Comment: you just sent me on a google quest to find out where i had missed the html5 documentation on the ticker tag.

Comment: @jason same here. @Erik, can't make up your own tags unless you are strictly targeting non-IE browsers. and even that is just wrong.

Comment: Good point. The intention was to strip them out on load, but I see these other side effects now. Thanks for your input, I'll work on changing them to legal HTML5 tags

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="ticker" id="AAPL">Apple</div>

$('.ticker').each(function(){
  $(this).html('(' + $(this).attr('id') + ') ' + $(this).html());
});
```

Comment: while this would work, i think @pointy's answer is probably better with the custom data attributes

Comment: data-symbol would flag an 'unknown attribute' error and it wouldn't validate. Not sure if anybody cares about w3 validation anymore but since he's concerned about his IE customers it might be an issue.

Comment: i think that so long as the doctype is html5, custom data attributes shouldn't break validation

Comment: html5 spec says attributes starting with `data-` will be treated as a storage area for private data. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes